# Listing network printers

Tags: c#

Trying to run the following (found here http://www.encodedna.com/2013/04/show-printers-using-wmi.htm ) to get a list of network printers but it only returns printers added to my machine

```
 System.Management.ManagementScope objMS = new System.Management.ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
        objMS.Connect();

        SelectQuery objQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
        ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objMS, objQuery);
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMOS.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject Printers in objMOC)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Local"]))       // LOCAL PRINTERS.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Local :- " + Printers["Name"]);
            }
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Network"]))     // ALL NETWORK PRINTERS.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Network :- " + Printers["Name"]);
            }
        }
```

I can view/add network printers in control panel. Just curious why it isn't showing them. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also get list of printers via static method InstalledPrinters of .NET class PrinterSettings (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters(v=vs.110).aspx). I've used it, and got network printers without problems.

Comment: Hi, this method also gives me only the local printers attached to my machine. Not the network printers.

Comment: Check this post, perhaps guy had same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902379/how-to-get-printers-from-network-which-is-not-installed-in-my-system

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach (string printerString in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{ 
    // do something
}
```